# How to make a SplashScreen in C# WindowsFormsApplication

Tags: c#, winforms, splash-screen

I was wondering how to make a SplashScreen in C#. I looked around StackOverflow but found nothing useful, can you help me please? I already have 1 form filled with stuff, I just need some simple instructions on how to:

- Make a new form appear before my main form
- Make the SplashScreen disappear and the main form appear after a few seconds (maybe three)

I don't need an animated splashscreen.
Thanks in advance!

Just ask if you need any code samples from me :)

Comment: Welcome to this site. Please try to show some knowledge with the code. Also, try this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673568/splash-screen-display-method-best-practice-c-sharp Or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455703/splash-screen-example

Comment: "I looked around StackOverflow but found nothing useful"? Unlikely. I found the duplicate (along with many others) by pasting your title into Google.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of a splashscreen - I have used in one of my projects - that uses multithreading:

```
namespace  WindowsForm1
{
    public enum SplashTypeOfMessage
    {   Success,    
        Warning,
        Error       
    }

    public partial class SplashForm : Form
    {
        static SplashForm _splashForm = null;
        static Thread _splashThread = null;
        public static object locker = new object(); 
        public  static bool WaitPlease = true;  

        private  SplashForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            lblLoading.Text = "Please wait Loading";
        }

        public static  void ShowSplashScreen()
        {            
            if (_splashForm != null)
                return;
            _splashThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(SplashForm.ShowSplash));
            _splashThread.IsBackground = true; 
            _splashThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA) ; 
            _splashThread.Start();
        }

        public static void ShowSplash()
        {
            if (_splashForm==null)
            {                
                _splashForm = new SplashForm();
                _splashForm.blueLoaderBar1.StartAnimation();

            }
              _splashForm.TopMost = true;
              _splashForm.Show();
              lock (SplashForm.locker)
              {
                  WaitPlease = false;
              }

            Application.Run(_splashForm);

        }

        delegate void CloseSplashHandler(SplashTypeOfMessage typeOfMessage, string message,bool itWasRinvoked);

        public static void CloseSplash(SplashTypeOfMessage typeOfMessage,string message,bool itWasrinvoked)
        {                             
            CloseSplashHandler closeSpalshHandler = new CloseSplashHandler(CloseSplash);
            bool launched=false;
            while (!launched && !itWasrinvoked)
            {
                lock (SplashForm.locker)
                {
                    if (!SplashForm.WaitPlease)
                    {
                        launched = true;
                    }
                }
             }

            if (_splashForm!=null && _splashThread!=null )
            {
                if (_splashForm.InvokeRequired)
                {
                    _splashForm.Invoke(closeSpalshHandler,new object[] {typeOfMessage,message,true});
                }
                else
                {                    
                    switch (typeOfMessage)
                    {
                        case SplashTypeOfMessage.Warning:
                            break;
                        case SplashTypeOfMessage.Error:
                            MessageBox.Show("Error");                                                  
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    _splashForm.Close();
                    _splashThread = null;

                }                                
            }
        }             
    }
}
```

Here is how you can call it:

```
SplashForm.ShowSplashScreen();
```

This is how you can close the splash screen:

```
SplashForm.CloseSplash(typeOfMessage ,string.Empty,false);
```

Comment: I have implemented your code and I think i need to add some using System.Something statements at the start, at the moment i have the default ones: using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;       Edit: I have removed some unneeded snippets but my IDE still doesn't recognise 'Thread'.

Comment: *cough* Get this: http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/

Comment: @Pyroglyph you need using System.Threading;

Comment: Okay I used common sense and tried using System.Threading and it seemed to work although Im not sure where to put SplashForm.ShowSplashScreen(); it wont show if i put it in SplashForm.cs and if i put it in my main form it insists that SplashForm doesnt exist in the current context when nearly everything in SplashForm is public!

Comment: in you  main method    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                    bool error = false; 
                    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                    SplashForm.ShowSplashScreen();

Comment: Im quite new to C# as you might have guessed but I put your code into SplashForm.cs and i thought my main method was in my main cs file (which isnt splashform.cs)? But i get a 'not in context' error. And the examples you gave me (Application.EnableVisualStyles(); bool error = false; Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);) dont actually appear on my code so im a bit stuck here :(

Comment: Ah i found the bits you referenced but i still get a not in the current context error with this:`         static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            SplashForm.ShowSplashScreen();
            Application.Run(new offlineWiki());
        }`

Comment: I dont have line numbers but i can give the whole Program.cs:  using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace OfflineMinecraftWiki
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            SplashForm.ShowSplashScreen();
            Application.Run(new offlineWiki());
        }
    }
}