# Creating and showing a WindowsForm from another Thread in another class - C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, class, invoke

**First:** I know that this problem has already been asked many times, but its really been several hours that I stagnate on this problem and I have not succeeded in applying the different solutions that I found to my problem.

I have a class program like this:

```
class Program
{
    private static UDProtocol MyUdp;

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        MyUdp = new UDProtocol();
        MyUdp.Start();
        Application.Run();
    }
}
```

And a class UDProtocol which I simplify like this:

```
class UDProtocol
{
    UdpMe = new UdpClient(11000);

    public void Start()
    {
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            CreateNewForm();

        }).Start();
     }

    public void CreateNewForm()
    {
        //Form f1 = new Form()
        //f1.Show()
    }
  }
```

When I do this (with the comments in CreateNewForm), I have my Form displayed, but the controls on it are all transparent like this :

[image]

I assumed this was from trying to create a from in a different thread, and I'm pretty sure I should use Invoke, but I really can't figure out how to do it.

Thank you

**EDIT : Solution**

`Application.Run(new Form())`;

adding this in the thread solve the issue. The form is displayed correctly

Comment: Doesn't look like it's anything to do with threading, the form is being created and accessed on a single thread. I don't get it, you want to create a new form every millisecond??

Comment: @Charlieface I see, no it's an error when I simplify the code so that it is readable specially for the question, I will edit it.

Comment: WPF and Winforms controls must be managed from an STA Thread (in this case, the Main Thread of the App), if you want to raise new Winforms controls/forms/events from other threads you should use the Dispatcher.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to start a UI thread in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/745057/how-to-start-a-ui-thread-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

The `UDProtocol` object should be generating events that a custom `Form` can use to display information to the user.

```
class Program {
    [STAThread]
    static void Main() {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        MyForm f1 = new MyForm();
        Application.Run(f1);
    }
}

public class UDProtocol {

    public event EventHandler SomeEvent;

    Thread tRead = null;
    public void Start() {
        // some internal thread starts
        if (tRead != null)
            throw new Exception("Already started.");

        tRead = new Thread(() => {
            while (true) {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                if (SomeEvent != null)
                    SomeEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        });
        tRead.IsBackground = true;
        tRead.Name = "UDProtocol.Read";
        tRead.Start();
    }
}

public class MyForm : Form {
    UDProtocol myUDP = new UDProtocol();

    public MyForm() {
        myUDP.SomeEvent += udp_SomeEvent;
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        myUDP.Start();
    }

    void udp_SomeEvent(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        this.BeginInvoke((Action) delegate {
            MessageBox.Show(this, "Some event happened in the UDP object.", "UDP Event");
        });
    }
}
```